# linq query methods all throwing NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
    var qry = from d in _dbEntities.DAY
              where d.DATE == DateTime.Now.Date
              select d;
    DAY day = qry.Single();
```

It's throwing a NotSupportedException when I try and run it. It should be returning 0 results, as there are 0 in there, and therefore should be throwing InvalidOperationException. I'm having the same problem with qry.Count(), and as far as I can tell any of the methods of IQueryable. I've looked up ways to get the count from a query and they all say use these methods

Comment: The results of running a LINQ query depend on the implementation of the object. It is absolutely "expected" that you may get `NotSupportedException` if you write LINQ queries that are not supported on a given provider. So, you will have to say what `_dbEntities` and `_dbEntities.DAY` is.

Comment: @Mark Could you show the structure of 'DAY' in your code?

Comment: By provider, do you mean what I'm using for my database? I'm using Entity Framework and SQL Server localdb that comes with VS2013 Premium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EF May be trying to convert `DateTime.Now.Date` to an expression which is not compatible with the provider.  Try making it a variable instead:

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;

var qry = from d in _dbEntities.DAY
          where d.DATE == today
          select d;
DAY day = qry.Single();
```

The reason you get that exception on `Single` is because the query is not actually *executed* until you try and *use* it (via  `foreach`, `ToList`, `Count`, `Single`, etc.).  That makes it *look like* the problem is with `Single` when the real problem is with the query itself.